# Grape POST request receiving JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-grape, grape-api

I am having problem with grape.
I have tried to look into their docs and google around.
I could not find any solution or sample regarding this.

Let say I am sending this kind of format to the POST request of grape:

```
 {
    "preferences": {
        "play": {
            "weekdays": "5",
            "weekend": "8"
        },
        "grow": {
            "weekdays": "4",
            "weekend": "8"
        }
    }
}
```

Questions:

1. How do I setup the Grape params to receive this post?
   I have tried something like this:

> ```
>   params do
>     optional :preferences, type: Hash  do
>       optional :play do
>         optional :weekdays
>         optional :weekend
>       end
>       optional :grow, type: Hash do
>         optional :weekdays
>         optional :weekend
>       end
>     end
>   end
> ```

2. I am using postman to do the POST on my chrome. My question is, How do I set the Hash kind of params ? There are 3 options on postman which are form-data, form-urlencoded, and raw. I have tried with form-data and raw (json) it does not work for the raw json, it gave me an error saying that 
   **The requested content-type 'text/plain' is not supported**

Any idea how do I fix these problems?

Thank you very much

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

**Answering question 1:** If all parameters are optional then you don't even need the `params` block. Get rid of it and, for example, use `params[:preferences][:play][:weekdays]` to access the weekdays attribute. Just use the same idea to access other values.

**Answering question 2:** On Postman, use RAW but don't forget to set the header `Content-Type` to `application/json`. I've written the code below to play around with this example.

```
require 'grape'

class API < Grape::API
    version 'v1', :using => :header, :vendor => 'alienlabz', :format => :json
    format :json
    resource :preferences do
        post do
            puts params[:preferences][:play][:weekdays]
        end
    end
end

run API
```